# Hibernate/JPA reflection issue

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, reflection

I'm trying to retrieve all data from a table in an MsSQL database using Hibernate 5.2.11.Final and using java reflection to get the value of a field in each row. This seems to be troublesome for Hibernate/JPA.

**The layout**

- Class A is abstract, single table type. Has string variable named "x"
- Class B inherits from A

**How I exact the data**

```
Field field = null;
try {
    field = A.class.getDeclaredField("x");
    field.setAccessible(true);
} catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

CriteriaQuery<A> query = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(A.class);
Root<A> root = query.from(A.class);
query.select(root);
ScrollableResults results = session.createQuery(query).setFetchSize(100).scroll(ScrollMode.FORWARD_ONLY);

while (results.next()) {
    Object entity = results.get(0);
    log.info(entity.getClass().getSimpleName() + " " + field.get(entity))
}
```

**This prints out:**

```
B test
B test2
B test3
B_$$_jvst26f_48c null
B test5
```

What is B_$$_jvst26f_48c? If I apply "entity instanceof A" it returns true - yet I cannot extract its value using reflection. If I cast the entity-object to class A and extract the value using .getX() then there's no issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

B_$$_jvst26f_48c is a proxy class generated by Hibernate to help lazy loading.

For instance assume some entity has a reference to a `B`, however that `B` might never be accessed so it might not be necessary to load it.

That proxy class will override the methods of B and add a test checking if the instance was loaded, i.e. something like (this is pseudocode):

```
@Override
public int getX() {
    if (!proxyIsLoaded) {
        loadProxy();
    }
    return super.get();
}
```

This way you can transparently call `getX()` you don't need to know it's proxy.

However as you have seen, accessing the fields through reflection does not work.

You can add the `@Proxy(lazy = false)` annotation to the class but this will disable a lot of lazy loading cases for this entity